# add series in if condition java

Tags: java, if-statement

I want to add series in if condition like this

```
if (count == 33 || count == 66 || count == 99
            || count == 132 || count == 165 || count == 198
            || count == 231 || count == 264 || count == 297
            || count == 330 || count == 363 || count == 396
            || count == 429 || count == 462 || count == 495
            || count == 528 || count == 561 || count == 594
            || count == 627 || count == 660 || count == 693
            || count == 726 || count == 759 || count == 792
            || count == 825 || count == 858 || count == 891
            || count == 924 || count == 957 || count == 990
            || count == 1023 || count == 1056 || count == 1089){
        retValue = true;
    }else {
        retValue = false;
    }
```

is there are any best way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, basically you are checking for divisibility by `33`, then just do that with modulus operator* :

```
if (count % 33 == 0) {
        retValue = true;
} else {
        retValue = false;
}
```

And if you want to confirm that range, you can add that to condition:

```
if (count >= 33 && count <= 1089 && count % 33 == 0)
```

Further you can reduce that `if-else` block to just a single `return` statement:

```
return count >= 33 && count <= 1089 && count % 33 == 0;
```

Comment: Little detail: He didn't include 0 in it's conditions.

Comment: Replaced it by a syntax error: `0 < c < 10` is maths, not programming.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux.. Yeah silly mistake. Taken care of that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use switch case to solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Use `ArrayList<Integer>`, fill it with the integer values. Then simply:

`list.contains(value)`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (count <=1089 && count%33==0){
   return true;
else
 return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<int> list = new ArrayList<int>() { 33, 66, 99, 132, 165, 1198 };// add your numbers to this List, this can be reuse in another parts of Program 

            if (list.Contains(count))
            {
                retValue = true;
                System.out.ptinrtln("Element Found");

            }
            else
            {
                retValue = false;
                 System.out.ptinrtln("Element Not Found");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was said, you can check `%33`, but if actually you need to check some list of arbitrary conditions, you can create answer iteratively

```
retValue = false;
do {

   // retValue = retValue || <newcondition>;
   retValue |= <newcondition>;


} while( !retValue );
return retValue;
```